# SOLR/Tika - I need to concat values from 2 columns from 2 entities

Tags: solr, concatenation, multiple-columns, apache-tika

Please look at my schema: http://pastebin.com/uPxwq8Zs and my data config: http://pastebin.com/ebeDfPM9

So, I need to index page content and some other fields and also all file attachments text, linked for each page. Because there can be multiple attachments, "text" and the rest fileds regarding to file need to be declared as multivalued. So, example output could be:

```
{
        "header": " ",
        "page_id": 25352,
        "title": "Informacje, których nie ma w BIP",
        "content": [
          "<p>   TEST test test"
        ],
        "file_name": [
          "Wniosek",
          "Wniosek"
        ],
        "file_desc": [
          "Wniosek o udostępnienie informacji publicznej - format PDF",
          "Wniosek o udostępnienie informacji publicznej - format RTF"
        ],
        "file_path": [
          "/mnt/storage/content/www/html/smartsite/src/data/resource/1/2/422/zalacznik_nr_1_wniosek.pdf",
          "/mnt/storage/content/www/html/smartsite/src/data/resource/1/2/422/zalacznik_nr_1_wniosek.rtf"
        ],
        "text": [
          "Dzień dobry -  dokument testowy.\nTEST.\n"
        ],
        "_version_": 1479310282003054600
      },
```

As you can see, it generallly works, but it's useless for me. In my example, there are 2 file attachments declared in database for page_id 25352. First attachment doesn't exist on disk on server, so tika was unable to index it, second attachment was indexed succesfully and this is text extracted:

```
"text": [
          "Dzień dobry -  dokument testowy.\nTEST.\n"
        ],
```

But I need to know, from which attachment was it extracted. So my idea is to concat my "text" field value with "file_patch" value and some separator, so I will get result like this:

```
"text": [
          /mnt/storage/content/www/html/smartsite/src/data/resource/1/2/422/zalacznik_nr_1_wniosek.rtf*"Dzień dobry -  dokument testowy.\nTEST.\n"
        ],
```

How to get result like this using solr/tike in my case?